# How do I initialize a UICollectionViewController with items that are sized relative to the container?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm trying to layout a grid of views. There should be 3 views per row. I tried to define my [UICollectionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/index.html)'s constructor as so:

```
- (id)initWithDefaultLayout
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    CGFloat dimension = floorf(self.view.frame.size.width / 3.0f);
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(dimension, dimension);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0f;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0f;
    return [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
}
```

The program crashed on the line that accessed self.view saying:

> NSException found: UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil
>   layout parameter

I suppose that the internal implementation of `loadView` saw that `UICollectionViewLayout` was not set and threw the exception.

How would I solve this issue in a clean way? The code would be fragile if I hardcoded the width of the items because there are various iOS screen sizes. Also, there are situations where this view controller is presented modally (smaller than the screen size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not override the sizeForItemAtIndexPath method - `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` - of the [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html):

Then you would just provide something like:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CGFloat viewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);

    int numCellsInRow = 3;

    // adjust for the spacing
    viewWidth -= ((numCellsInRow+1)*1.0f); 

    CGFloat dimension = viewWidth/(float)numCellsInRow;


    return CGSizeMake(dimension, dimension);
}
```

Comment: Yes. This makes the programming similar to UITableView